# Date/Time on Articles <time>

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, blogs

This is a fairly simple question. While I'll certainly accept and appreciate a detailed answer, guidance in the right direction is all I'm looking for as I have no qualms about learning. I still consider myself an amatuer so please forgive me if you find this trivial.

I'm sure you've all seen what I'm looking for here if you've read a blog or any type of news site. Articles usually have some type of heading with "1 Year Ago", "28 Minutes Ago", etc to reflect the difference in time from when an article was published to the current time you are looking at it. What I'm trying to figure out is how that is accomplished?

I learned today that a  tag exists but so far I haven't been able to determine how the attributes you can assign to (e.g. datetime="2015-04-27 20:00") it turn into a readable "1 Year Ago". In my head, I'm imagining some ways I might be able to do this with JavaScript but I'm wondering if this is how it's typically done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The tag does nothing except mark the text as pertaining to a specific date/time value. You need to format the date. You could look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What you might have read is that the "special attributes" actually are pseudo-attributes in some front end framework like Angular, React or Vue etc.
In angular they are known as custom directives. Where you can define custom attribute to pass some data into angular code and get some thing back in this case the humanized form of a date.
What you probably want is moment.js and some way to pass the the date into moment.js to parse it if your not using Angular or other frameworks. Since you are nt so descriptive about your code behind I leave it here on how to work that thing out.
A simple example to demonstrate [Moment.js Time from now](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)

```
moment([2007, 0, 29]).fromNow(); // 4 years ago
```